# How to make a div move with the mouse cursor smoothly?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to achieve the mouse effect on carousel (https://advertising.nytimes.com/custom-content/). the cursor should change when I hover over the container. I got it working but it is stutters a lot. How to make it smooth? the stutter occurs when I add the conditional statement. Please help.

```
<style>
            .img {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                object-fit: cover;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            .container {
                width: 700px;
                height: 900px;
                background-color: orangered;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: none;
            }
</style>
```

```
<div class="container">
            <img
                class="img"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472457897821-70d3819a0e24?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2669&q=80"
            />
 </div>
```

```
        <script>
            const container = document.querySelector(".container");
            const img = container.querySelector(".img");

            document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
                if (event.target == container) {
                    img.style.transform = `translate3d(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px, 0)`;
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as adding a Logical OR next to the `event.target == container`. It was moving weirdly because when your mouse would go over the image it would not be the target anymore.

To fix this we need to add an ID to the image so we can source it in our `event.target`. So out `<img>` would look something like this

`<img class="img" id"img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-147245789782170d3819a0e24ixlib=rb4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2669&q=80"/>`

After we set the id we are able to add the logical OR statement, it would look like this

`event.target == container || picture`

Hope I could help!

Comment: THANKS! that thought didn't occur to me. Setting pointer-events: none;  on img also fixes it!

Comment: Also if you dont want your question to get taken down you might want to add a little more explaining the problem. What I do is I imagine I dont know what the issue is and see if I can a understand it!